# Ruby undefined method for variable

Tags: ruby, nomethoderror

I have a bit of code that goes:

```
def strip_str(str)
  if str.nil?
    return ""
  end
  return I18n.transliterate(UnicodeUtils.downcase(str.force_encoding("utf-8"))).gsub(/\s+/, " ")
end

city_info = []

transactions.each do |trx|
  city = strip_str(trx["city"])
  event_city = strip_str(trx["event_city"])

  cities_dist = Levenshtein.distance city event_city
  cities_normal_dist = Levenshtein.normalized_distance city event_city
  cities_equal = (city == event_city)

  city_info << [cities_dist, cities_normal_dist, cities_equal]
end
```

This runs normally for a bunch of elements in `transactions` but eventually at one point where `city = 'manaus'` and `event_city = 'manaus'`, I get:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `city' for main:Object
```

on the `cities_equal = (city == event_city)` line. That seems to make no sense to me, as I'm just comparing two strings and none of them is being called as a method. What's wrong with this bit of code?

Comment: I would double check the data. THis would happen if `trx["city"]` is `nil`

Comment: `Levenshtein.distance city event_city` is missing a comma between `city` and `event_city`, assuming these are two arguments to the `distance` method (same for `normalized_distance`)

Comment: I added a `begin rescue` to that part of the code to check and `trx["city"]` was definitely not `nil`, and in any case `strip_str` should have taken care of that shoudln't it?

Comment: @Stefan aha yes you're right i completely missed that! Thank you.